# for-loop to iteratively subtract and add as a new value in the array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a data that consists of array inside array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [[[1,2,3,4,5],[0,0,0,0,0]], [[5,4,3,2,1],[0,0,0,0,0], [1,2,3,4,5]]]})
```

It looks like this:

```
     Col1
0   [[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,0,0,0]]
1   [[5,4,3,2,1], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

What I want to do is subtract second value of each array and add it as a new value inside the array. For example:

```
     Col1
0   [[1,2,3,4,5, 0], [0,0,0,0,0, -2]]
1   [[5,4,3,2,1, 0], [0,0,0,0,0, -4], [0,5,0,0,0, 5]]
```

As you can see, in the first row I want to subtract 0 and 2 resulting -2.
How I approached it was:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp = df2.loc[i, "Col1"]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        delta = temp[j][1] - temp[j-1][1]
        temp = temp.append(delta)
```

This is nowhere close from what I want to do.. Can anyone please help me how to figure this out??

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out :')

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp = df.loc[i, "Col1"]
    for j in range(0, 1):
        delta = 0
        temp[j].append(delta)
    for k in range (1, len(temp)):
        delta = temp[k][1] - temp[k-1][1]
        temp[k].append(delta))
    print(temp)
```